# How do I set up cascading dropdownlists in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I got an angular dropdown list with some options. Lets say we have a dropdown list with

[List]
A
B
C
D
E
F

If you choose A you will see another dropdownlist with:

[List]
A-1 
A-2
A-3
A-4

And with B
[List]
B-1
B-2
 

So the second list depends on what you choose in the first list. So far i got this.

## Html

```
<div class="" ng-show="signIn">
    <select ng-model="myProject" ng-options="proj.title for proj in projects | unique:'title'"><option value="">-- choose project --</option></select>
    <select ng-options="myProject.name"></select>
</div>
```

The problem is i cant use the binded variable in the first list.. What is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

This actually depends on your data structure, and how you retrieve it. I've mocked up an example of using a nested structure like this:

```
$scope.list = [
    {
        name:'A',
        items: [
            'A-1',
            'A-2',
            'A-3',
            'A-4'
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'B',
        items: [
            'B-1',
            'B-2'
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'C'
    }
];
```

Here's the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/hRz8G/

See if you can use it, maybe you'll need to adjust your data structure. If that's impossible, post your data structure, we might be able to work out a solution.

### Update

Try this example, and see if it fits your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/hRz8G/3/

It's traversing the projects list, and nests all the tasks inside of the project in a tasks-array.

```
[{
  "projectId":1,
  "title":"someTitle",
  "user":"mike",
  "tasks":[
    {"taskId":1,"name":"Sales"},
    {"taskId":3,"name":"Support"}
  ]
},
...
]
```

I hope that's kind of the solution you're looking for.

There's a filter defined, that keeps things tidy. Unfortunately it's kind of tightly bound to the project-object structure. If the id fieldname (`'projectId'`) changes, you'll need to change the filter too, but that's kind of a problem I'm struggling to solve.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i mean. The only things is the thing you said about my data structure. I get data via a post to my php and i get JSON data back. The data looks something like this. {projectId: 1, title: someTitle, user:mike, taskId: 1, name: Sales},{projectId: 1, title: someTitle, user:mike, taskId: 3, name: Support},{projectId: 1, title: someTitle, user:mike, taskId: 4, name: Finance},{projectId: 1, title: someTitle, user:mike, taskId: 1, name: Sales}. I would like to have a dropdown menu with projectId = 1 and the second dropdown with the different taskId's

Comment: Quite difficult, at the moment I can't figure out a better way, but displaying two dropdowns with all the project ids and task ids: http://jsfiddle.net/hRz8G/1/. This solution doesn't filter the task ids by project id. Maybe restructuring your data is a better approach.

Comment: Hmm, Maybe i should change the structure of my data.. not sure in what way though.. Anyways, thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: This is the best I could figure out: http://jsfiddle.net/hRz8G/2/ I'm getting back to you, if I find a solution

Comment: Yes, thanks man. Oh i just tried a filter. filter:myProject.title and I changed the ng-model of the select to myProject.title. It now only shows 1 of the options i have. So i have to loop through it or somehow

Comment: Hmm.. It does look good and does exactly what it suppose to do.. But yea the problem is like what you said.. If someone changes the data structure the filter becomes unable to work..

Answer (score 1):

So I got the answer. I thought I knew the answer but i didn't.. I did everything the same and this time it worked =S.. Also thanks to you Fiddle I created my drop down list. I filtered the projects with 'myProject.title' but it didn't work. So I outputted the 'myProject' and it gave me this information back.

{"projectId":"1056","title":"someTitle","user":"mike","taskId":"3","name":"Design"}

So when i got this back i thought i filtered it with the whole json file. (which is not true..) But then i changed my select input to ng-change and called a function -> selectedProject(myProject). In that function i got the title of the project and i returned it back. In my second drop down list i changed it to 'filter:selectedProject' and it suddenly worked.. I was like huh? so i thought it would be faster if we just filtered the drop down list with the input of the first. So i filtered it with myProject.title and it also worked.. So i still don't know the answer but this is my code now. The controller code is just some $http.post function

## HTML file

```
<div class='timesheet' ng-controller="timesheetController">

    <div class="" ng-show="signIn">
        <select ng-model="title" ng-options="proj.title for proj in projects | unique:'title'"><option value="">-- choose project --</option></select>
        <select ng-model="taskId" ng-options="proj.name for proj in projects | filter:title.title"></select>
            {{title.title}}{{taskId.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. I didn't notice you already had the unique filter in place, so you probably use angular-ui or a custom filter like that. I'm OK with you accepting your answer as a solution ;)

Comment: haha, yes. I had some multiple information with different taskId's so I used the unique filter to remove the duplicates. Anyways.. Thanks for your help. =]